# How can I get f.lux working?

Tags: 12.04

I've installed the fluxgui package from Killian Valkhof's PPA (https://launchpad.net/~kilian/+archive/f.lux) and started the applet by pressing alt+f2 and typing in fluxgui.

The inidcator icon shows up and I've entered my latitude/longitude, but my screen colors aren't changing.  The applet fails to open its preferences dialogue as well.

What gives?  Any solutions?

Comment: f.lux is now available for Ubuntu through Launchpad PPA. You can install this using Terminal. Execute the following commands one-by-one to install `f.lux` on Ubuntu. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kilian/f.lux sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install fluxgui After installation it'll appear in Ubuntu indicator. Click the f.lux icon from the app indicator menu and click on Preferences. Now give your latitude and longitude. If you don't know yours, that's okay. You'll find an option beneath to find your latitude and longitude. It'll direct to a web address. Name your area in the search bar. Select t

Comment: so is there anyone who have done it?

Comment: This actually installs and launches fine, but it does not change temperature at all on Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: I got f.lux running but the preference panel won't open. So not sure if it's actually doing something.

Comment: @Voles, I think you're having the same problem as the rest of us.  The good news is that F.lux just pushed an update (the first in a number of years), so these issues may soon get fixed... maybe.

Comment: I've got f.lux working on OSX, exited about the update! However I'd like to use it on Ubuntu as well. Thanks for you reply!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Having the same problems with f.lux and there doesn't seem to be any fix for this right now.

But [Redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/) seems to work fine on Ubuntu 12.04.

[`gtk-redshift`](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gtk-redshift) in Ubuntu Software Centre

Answer (score 4):

I got f.lux working by downloading the xflux daemon available from http://justgetflux.com/linux.html. I cannot get the GUI panel to open but can configure xflux via the command line and the f.lux icon says it is active.